# Python, BeautifulSoup: Output XML not recognized by program?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, arcgis

I'm running into some strange problems with using BeautifulSoup for editing XML. After I read in the XML file and make all of my edits, I write it to a file using

```
output = open("output.xml", "r")
output.write(str(soup))
output.close
```

However, the program that needs to read in this XML file does not even recognize it exists (it's supposed to automatically load XML. For any reference this is ArcGis). I can open up the original XML and the Python-generated one and verify that they are completely identical--at least visually.

Another quirky behavior is that if I open the original XML file and make edits to it with a text editor and save, there is no error with the program and it loads correctly. If I make edits using Python but NOT with BeautifulSoup (i.e. string operations) it also works fine. it seems that writing the output string with BeautifulSoup causes the problem.

Is this some kind of encoding issue? What's the difference between a string obtained from the BeautifulSoup object and a normal string read straight from a file?

Comment: Maymbe you save it in wrong place if program says that file doesn't exist.

Comment: In the shown code you don't close the file.  You actually have to _call_ the `close()` method and not just reference it and do nothing with it.  Unless it is closed it may not be written to disk in full and maybe the other program doesn't read it until it recognises a ”close event” on the file.

Comment: Oh, and opening a file for reading and then trying to write into it, results in a runtime error.  Also I would open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't direct-copy-and-paste, I do close the file properly and I don't read/write simultaneously to one file, they are different files. Also, the file is written to the correct directory. I can perform the exact same operations without using BeautifulSoup and everything is fine, then if I do use it then the file is not recognized. As I mentioned before, I can open up both input and output XMLs and verify they are identical.

Comment: Can you please show a minimal example that just reads and writes an **XML** file with BeautifulSoup?  Which version are you using, and how do you make sure the _HTML_ scraper doesn't treat the data as _HTML_ instead of _XML_? (Answer to that depends on BeautifulSoup version.)  Any chance the written XML contains extra tags at the beginning/end like `<html>` and `<body>`?